# Add my own jar to jmeter lib directory without maven groupId and artifactId

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-maven-plugin

I hava some Java code, this is going to be used in Bean Shell.

The Java code I have already exported from IDEA and generated to a jar file, so it does not hava maven groupId.

How can I add this jar file to the jmeter/lib directory?

Here is the [jmeter-maven-plugin wiki](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is **you** who defines groupId/artifactId for your jar file, once you have the .jar you can install it into your local Maven repository using [Maven Install Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html#The_install:install-file_goal) like

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/path/to/your.jar -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=my-cool-jar -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

Once done you should be normally able to [add the .jar to JMeter Classpath](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath) like:

```
<testPlanLibraries>
     <artifact>com.example:my-cool-jar:1.0</artifact>
</testPlanLibraries>
```

And last but not the least, [since JMeter 3.1 you should not be using Beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), consider switching to [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) language

Comment: I knew that way，but as I said the jar artifact is not a maven project，there is no groupId. I hava tried the `maven-resources-plugin`, it‘s working. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can add jar to Test Plan:

Click Browse and add your file, then you can call your java code from Beanshell or JSR223 script

Notice that if your jar has dependencies, you will have to add them too.